# Executing Dynamic SQL into Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to pivot data based on a variable number of rows and apply the total number of rows as columns in order to create a normalized matrix.

I need to reference the output of this elsewhere, so I am attempting to execute this dynamic SQL into a temp table for use later.

Besides the headache of having to create a table to house the expected output of my dynamic SQL, when I create a table structure that is identical to the output and attempt to `EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery` I'm unable to do so unless I add an additional column.

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

So I add a +1 here and I can get the EXEC statement to run, but it repeats the RowID in the column labeled '1'

```
 WHILE @iCount <= (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM #Input) + 1
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Full procedure:

```
if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Input') is not null drop table #Input
if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Matrix') is not null drop table #Matrix

CREATE TABLE #Input 
(
    RowID INT,
    ColumnID INT,
    Val FLOAT
)

CREATE TABLE #Matrix
(
     RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

INSERT INTO #Input
VALUES (1, 1, 0.96), (1, 2, -0.036), (2, 1, -0.034), (2, 2, 0.97)

DECLARE @iCount INT=1

--Alter table to include columns that allow for executing dynamic sql into temp table
WHILE @iCount <= (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM #Input) + 1     --I don't want to add this third column, but SQL fails otherwise
BEGIN
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE #Matrix ADD [' + @iCount +'] FLOAT')

    SELECT @iCount = @iCount + 1
END

--Create dynamic SQL to populate Matrix
DECLARE @PivotColumns as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLQuery as NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumns=coalesce(@PivotColumns +',','') +QUOTENAME(ColumnID)
FROM (Select DISTINCT ColumnID FROM #Input) as A


SELECT * FROM #Input
Set @SQLQuery=
    N'Select RowID,' + @PivotColumns + '
    FROM #Input
    PIVOT(MAX(Val)
      FOR ColumnID IN(' + @PivotColumns + ')) as P'

--display the dynamic sql results
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

--now place this same sql into the table created above
INSERT INTO #Matrix EXEC (@SQLQUERY)

--and display. Why the difference?
select * from #Matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was the `IDENTITY(1,1)` in the #Matrix table definition.  Removing this allowed the procedure to run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following

```
...
CREATE TABLE #Matrix
(
     RowID INT --IDENTITY(1,1)
)
...
WHILE @iCount <= (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM #Input) -- + 1
...
```